# Problem/Exercise: Schrödinger's cat (QM)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedingers-cat

I've been struggling for a day with the following problem on Quantum coherent states, so I was wondering if you could tell me if I'm going in the right direction (I've checked the books of Sakurai and Weinberg but can't seem to find a satisfactory answer)

> Suppose a Schrödinger cat state given by $|\alpha_+\rangle :=N(|\alpha\rangle+|-\alpha\rangle)$, where $|\alpha\rangle$ are the coherent states of the harmonic oscillator and $N$ is a constant of proportionality. Verify the relationship of Robertson-Schrödinger for $X$ and $P$ operators.

The solution is simple as we only have to calculate $\langle x \rangle$, $\langle p \rangle$, $\langle x^2 \rangle$, $\langle p^2 \rangle$, and $rel(x,p)$.

From the definition of coherent states, $a|\alpha\rangle=\alpha|\alpha\rangle$ and with $x=x_0(a+a^\dagger)$, I began by calculating $\langle x \rangle$ in the following way:
\begin{align}
\langle x \rangle 
& = \langle\alpha_+|x|\alpha_+\rangle
\\ & = (\langle\alpha|+\langle{-\alpha}|)x(|\alpha\rangle+|{-\alpha}\rangle)
\\
\langle x \rangle
& =\langle\alpha|x|\alpha\rangle+\langle\alpha|x| {-\alpha}\rangle+\langle-\alpha|x|\alpha\rangle+\langle-\alpha|x|-\alpha\rangle
\\ & = \frac{x_0}{\sqrt{2}}(\langle\alpha|a+a^\dagger|\alpha\rangle+\langle\alpha|a+a^\dagger|-\alpha\rangle+\langle-\alpha|a+a^\dagger|\alpha\rangle+\langle-\alpha|a+a^\dagger|-\alpha\rangle)
\end{align}

From the definition $a|\alpha\rangle=\alpha|\alpha\rangle$, we deduce $\langle\alpha| a^\dagger=\langle\alpha| \alpha^{*}$.

Moreover (I'm not entirely sure of this step), by replacing $\alpha'\rightarrow-\alpha$ we deduce that $a|{-\alpha}\rangle=-\alpha|{-\alpha}\rangle$ and $\langle{-\alpha}| a^\dagger=\langle-\alpha| {-\alpha^{*}}$.

Applying the operators to the above expression, we finally get:

$$\langle x \rangle=x_0 ((a+a^{*})+(-a+a^{*})+(a-a^{*})+(-a-a^{*}))=0$$

In an analogous manner, $\langle p \rangle=0$.

So far, is this correct? My main doubt comes with the eigenvalues of the coherent states for $|{-\alpha}\rangle$.

Comment: It looks correct.  Intuitively it’s clear that $\langle x\rangle=0$. Less class for $\langle p\rangle$ but this is motion of the centroid of the state, so symmetry suggests it is also $0$.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation. Thus far your formalism is correct but we don't do check-my-work; if you have a specific question about the handling of $a|{-\alpha}⟩$ then ask that directly and concisely.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I understand, then I will pose more specifically the question I have in this problem.